# Django not serving static image file

Tags: python, django

Django is currently not displaying the profile.jpg file in the template. I looked at some tutorials but it didn't solve the issue. Any suggestions on how to serve the static files?

I'm using Django version 1.10.6

settings.py:

```
    """

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'send_email',
    'resume',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
...

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
...


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/resume/static/'
```

Heres the line inside the template where I'm trying to display the image:

```
<img src="{% static 'resume/img/profile.jpg' %}" class="responsive-img" style='max-height:100px;' alt="face">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your settings

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static') 
STATIC_URL = '/resume/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "staticfiles")]
```

Answer (score 0):

you're not saying if this is in a production or not-production environment. I assume it is production as you have `DEBUG = FALSE` in the example.

If that's the case you will have to point whichever http server you're using to where your `static/` folder lives (and do not forget about `media/` if you can upload files). Here you have an example for Apache: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files

If you're under development, take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/ and you should be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

Before you use static files, you need to load them with the following line in your template

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

Comment: I already had that line inside my template, with DEBUG = True. I switched toDEBUG = False but it didn't fix the issue

Comment: It is not staticfiles it is:
`{% load static %}`

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the source code, see what's the rendered image url.
Check whether that url is valid or not.